# Reload after being redirected to a URL

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redirect, routes

I currently am logging into my web application

I am using redirect, something like this:

```
if (token) {
       return <Redirect to="/home" />
}
```

How can I reload the page *right* when we reach /home? Ideally we would do something like window.location.reload(true) but how do we do it as the very first thing the page is rendered?
I'm using frontend React for my framework.

Thanks!

Comment: You can call `window.location.reload()` on `componentDidMount()` on the page, but if you reload the page as soon it is opened, it would possibly create an infinite loop, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that would create an infinite loop, I already tested that-- it's because as soon as the page reloads componentwillmount will be called-- thus generating an infinite loop. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I also can't use something like href because it would then not pass in my login information, making the user not authenticated